# AngularJS : reusing controllers functions on big projects

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I need your help concerning AngularJS best practises for big application and to reuse controllers functions again and again.

I already follow best practises(John Papa, Todd Motto, ...) but I am stucked on a particular thing.

I will give an example to illustrate my question.

Let's imagine we got an app with members and we want to allow members block/unblock each other. They can block an other user on three views (user profile with a button, blocked users page entering a username and on a messenger page with some sort of popover).

We create a service to handle all blocked method(block, unblock, ...) and this service is directly linked to an Api.

My concern is with controllers :

```
function blockUser(userId) {
  Popup.show('Are you sure you want to block this user?').then(function () {
    BlockService.blockUser(userId).then(function () {
      // Do things
      $state.go('blocked-users');
    });
  });
}
```

Here we want to show a Popup asking the user if he is sure to block the other user. If he says Yes the Popup resolves and we block the other user.
When the Api method resolves, we do things like redirecting the user on the list of blocked users.

For the three views and their controllers, it's exactly the same function again and again.

I can see 3 solutions to only write this function once :

1) Defining it in the RootScope (but it's a bad practise)

2) Moving this code on the service (but it feels weird to show a Popup and redirecting a user in a service, but maybe it's the best solution)

3) Creating a global BlockController and pasting it directly on template when we use block methods (but declaring the same ng-controller X times feels wrong)

What is the best way to handle such cases?

Answer (score 0):

It appears your best option would most likely be a service. The benefit of a service is its accessible from any controller and easy to make changes/updates. 
If you have a separate function for each controller you'd have to change every one each time you make a change and it can get hard to keep clean. Lastly avoid rootScope as much as possible, its considered bad practice and this is definitely not a case where you need Root access.